# Should the Paperclip 3 file "paperclip_attachments.yml" be included or omitted from Git commits?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

When I issue the command: `rake paperclip:refresh:missing_styles`, a file is generated in `/public/system/paperclip_attachments.yml` by Paperclip 3 (using Rails 3). What I'm wondering is would it be better to included or exclude this file from Git commits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can leave it out, as it's created when running `rake paperclip:refresh:missing_styles`. A typical scenario is to run the command on the production server when deploying with Capistrano.